# syntax error near unexpected token - R package Install

Tags: r

I am trying to install an R package along with its dependencies. But it is throwing error.

```
$ install.packages(rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz, dependencies=True)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz,'
```

I am new to R please help me how can I download this along with it dependencies.

Before this, I tried following

```
$ R CMD INSTALL rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘magrittr’, ‘selectr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
```

But it failed with dependent packages are missing error. And obviously it is cumbersome to install the dependent packages manually. Hence I tried package.install

Comment: You can use `devtools`:

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it with **quotes** and capital `TRUE`:

```
install.packages("rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Note this will only work if you have unix-like system and the file is located in your current working directory (check with running `getwd()` from your R session). Otherwise you need to provide full path to the file (like `"~/somefolder/mydata/rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz"`).

If you run Windows, then you need `.zip` file instead of `.tar.gz`.

If you are connected to internet, just run:

```
install.packages("rvest")
```